# Data Constructor not in scope - Haskell

Tags: haskell, constructor

I am new to Haskell so I apologise if this is an obvious mistake to some. I have been trying to add a tuple to a list of tuples, however I get an errors like `Data constructor not in scope: Adelle :: String` and `Data constructor not in scope: Hello :: String` when I input: `addRecord tData Hello Adelle` into GHCi.

I have done some research and some people suggested to others that their variables have to be lower case, which mine are. So I am unsure what is causing the issue. Any help is hugely appreciated.

My code is below:

```hs
type Sales = (String, String, Int)

tData :: [Sales]
tData = [("No Lie", "Sean Paul feat. Dua Lipa",  100),
         ("Fear & Delight", "The Correspondents",  120)]

addRecord :: [Sales] -> String -> String -> [Sales]
addRecord dataset songName artist = dataset ++ [(songName, artist, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put double quotes around your strings:

```
addRecord tData "Hello" "Adelle"
```

Comment: Well I feel a bit stupid with how dumb that was. Thank you so much @Aplet123. Is there a way I could save the returned result of addRecord actually into tData so the list changes rather than just printing the list of tData with the user input added on the end.

Comment: In Haskell, variables are immutable. That's part of the core language design. If you want to change the data, you can either use IORef/STRef (will involve a monad every time you want to edit/retrieve the value), or the easier method of just saving to a different variable.